# How would i get rid of a frame, whats placed on a frame when wanting to display another frame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

As you can see by the code, on the MainWindow it should display a blue and a green box, one ontop of the other and then the SecondMainWindow should have a red and yollow box displaying on ontop of the other. By running the code you can see that from the `login` window to the `MainWindow` all the frames remain as they should due to them only being on the `MainWindow`and the `SecondMainWindow`
However the problem persists when you go from the `MainWindow` to the `SecondMainWindow` where the fames are getting mixed up with which window thier on. I've set the background to `MainWindow` and `SecondMainWindow` to different colours to further develop an understanding on what frame should be shown.

```
import tkinter as tk
class start(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
     tk.Tk.__init__(self)
     self.frame = login()
     self.frame.grid()

  def change(self, frame):
    self.frame.grid_forget()
    self.frame = frame()
    self.frame.grid()


class login(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
    self.master.geometry('300x300')
    self.master.configure(bg='orange')

    button1 = tk.Button(self.master, text='New Frame', command = self.ChangeFrame).grid(row=0,column=0)

  def ChangeFrame(self):
    self.master.change(MainWindow)


class MainWindow (tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
    self.master.geometry('300x300')
    self.master.configure(bg='white')

    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=3)

    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    Frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master, background='blue', bd=1, relief='sunken')
    Frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='nsew')

    Frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master, background='green', bd=1, relief='sunken')
    Frame2.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='nsew')

    button1 = tk.Button(Frame1, text='New Frame', command = self.ChangeFrame).grid(row=0,column=0)

  def ChangeFrame(self):
    self.master.change(SecondMainWindow)

class SecondMainWindow (tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
    self.master.geometry('300x300')
    self.master.configure(bg='grey')

    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.master.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

    Frame3 = tk.Frame(self.master, background='yellow', bd=1, relief='sunken')
    Frame3.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='nsew')

    Frame4 = tk.Frame(self.master, background='red', bd=1, relief='sunken')
    Frame4.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky='nsew')

    button1 = tk.Button(Frame4, text='New Frame', command = self.ChangeFrame).grid(row=0,column=0)

  def ChangeFrame(self):
    self.master.change(MainWindow)    

app = start()
app.mainloop()
```

With only `self` being used
[image]

With only `self.master` being used
[image]

As you can see when using, just self it alters with the layout, how would i fix this?

Comment: If you want bigFrame > smallFrame then you have to provide bigFrame as the master to small frame: `smallFrame(bigFrame)`. In your case: `self.frame = login_window(self)`

Comment: How would that work in terms of still having the login window when the application starts?

Comment: I didn't mean that specifically, I mean in general. All of them need to just use 'self' as the master, and when that is done you need to fix your layout how you want it.

Comment: Please  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's hard to read about "BigFrame > SmallerFrames > Objects" and the reconcile that with some random piece of code.

Comment: @Byran Oakley - I have updated the question in response to your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing widgets for every window in `self.master` but the code that you copied from was designed so that each window is an independent object. All of the widgets in a single window must be children of that window.

In short, instead of this:

```
class SecondMainWindow (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        ...
        Frame3 = tk.Frame(self.master, ...)
        Frame4 = tk.Frame(self.master, ...)
        ...
```

You should be doing this:

```
class SecondMainWindow (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        ...
        Frame3 = tk.Frame(self, ...)
        Frame4 = tk.Frame(self, ...)
        ...
```

If you want every window to put widgets directly in the root window, there's no reason for you to create classes that inherit from `tk.Frame`.

Comment: I've just further updated the question to show images of what happens when only using self, and not self.master. Any thoughts on how to fix the layout? Thanks in advance